# strange behavior about CActiveDataProvider with cache db query

Tags: php, mysql, caching, yii

I know when `pagination` is `false`, `CActiveDataProvider` use from single query.
So I write this code:

```
$dependency = new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT MAX(id) FROM user');
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider(User::model()->cache(20, $dependency), array('pagination'=>false));
```

When data was cached, This single query executed:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM user
```

After 20 sec, cache was refreshed and so have this queries:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` `t`
SELECT MAX(id) FROM user
```

Also if I insert one record in `User` table, because it is in dependency, this queries executed:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` `t`
SELECT MAX(id) FROM user
```

All here seem ok, and no problem.

Now I try another test with this sample query:

```
$dependency = new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT MAX(id) FROM user');
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider(User::model()->cache(20, $dependency, 2));
```

I know in the above code `CActiveDataProvider` use from two queries.

When data was cached, executed these queries:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM user
SELECT MAX(id) FROM user
```

It's strange! (Why?!)

And after 20 sec, cache was refreshed and I see executed these queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user` `t`
SELECT MAX(id) FROM user
SELECT * FROM `user` `t` LIMIT 10
SELECT MAX(id) FROM user
```

Now, I have 4 queries here!!!

Finally I insert one record in table and because dependency must refresh cache, But I see 6 queries here (and not 4 queries) !!!

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM user
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user` `t`
SELECT MAX(id) FROM user
SELECT MAX(id) FROM user
SELECT * FROM `user` `t` LIMIT 10
SELECT MAX(id) FROM user
```

This behavior is very strange! (Why?!)

I thinks it's a bug.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Salam hamvatan,
I have this problem and very searched about. I understand if which of $duration or $dependency will be expired, cache expired too.
My code example:

```
$dependency->sql = 'SELECT MAX(create_date),MAX(update_date),count(id) FROM game where status=:NOT_DONE';
$dependency->params = array(':NOT_DONE'=>Game::NOT_DONE);   
$games = new CActiveDataProvider(Game::model()->cache(3600*24*30,$dependency,1));
```

> I know when pagination is false, CActiveDataProvider use from single
>   query.

This statement help me, thanks. I was searching for this.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#queryCachingDuration-detail

Answer (score -1):

If you're rending your view with renderPartial, you should set $processOutput parameter to be true to avoid multiple ajax call.

Comment: I don't use `renderPartial` and don't use `AJAX` !